# Mocking intrinsic functions on top of serverless-framework

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a simple aws lambda function written in node.js on top of the serverless framework. My `serverless.yml` file contains calls to aws intrinsic functions (Fn::GetAtt).

In the example below, I am making a call to `Rds`, which is a `Custom::StackOutput` to get my database password, which would be saved to an environment variable and used by the lambda function:

```
functions:
  exampleLambda:
    description: "connect to database"
    environment:
      DB_USERNAME: user
      DB_DATABASE: db
      DB_PASSWORD:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - Rds
          - Password
```

Is there a way to mock the calls to these intrinsic functions when using the command `serverless invoke local --function exampleLambda`? In other words, mock the response value of Fn::GetAtt(rds, password)? Otherwise, I would not be able to run the invoke local command successfully as the function depends on the output of the intrinsic functions.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Silly question here, but you've already invoking locally right? I haven't come across a situation where any of the local breaks with serverless.

Comment: Could you please add part of the `serverless.yml` file? (showing how you are using the intrinsic functions) Maybe I won't be able to answer, but it will make the question clearer to others.

Comment: updated with an example! I have a workaround (mocking env variables during test), but its suboptimal as I need to manually change the code. If there is a better way to do it, let me know! Thanks!